# Connection to SQL Server not Working

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I using vb.net 2010 and sql server management express 2008. bu I little confused what is wrong with the code for connect sql and vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1
  Public Class connection
    Public Function GetConnect()
      Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing
      Dim connString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial  Catalog=dbMedical;Integrated Security=true"
      conn = New SqlConnection(connString)
      conn.Open()
      If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        Return False
      Else
        Return True
      End If
    End Function
  End Class
End Module
```

but but it does not work, error message appears.

Comment: 4 of 5 questions with all downvotes? Really, it's time to [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) or [leave](http://stackoverflow.com/users/logout).

Answer (score 0):

You have an inner class inside of a Module, is that what you really wanted? Apart from that, you cannot open connections etc. outside of a method context and that is what you've made iny our `connection`-Class. Create a method that returns the connection.

For example:

```
Public NotInheritable Class DatabaseFactory

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetConnection(openNow as Boolean) As SqlConnection
            Const connString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=dbMedical;Integrated Security=true"
            Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
            If openNow Then conn.Open()
            Return conn 
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Imports System.Data
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient      
 Module Connect  
 Public con As SqlConnection     
    Public Function GetConnect()
    con = New SqlConnection("Data Source='(LOCAL)';Initial Catalog='School';Database='School';User ID='sa';Password='';")
    Return con
    End Function
  End Module
```

After in form activated event:

```
con=GetConnect()
con.open()
-----
-----
con.close()
```